# Does DROP COLUMN block on a postrgeSQL database

Tags: postgresql

I have the following column in a postgreSQL database

```
column | character varying(10) | not null default 'default'::character varying
```

I want to drop it, but the database is huge and if it blocks updates for an extended period of time I will be publicly flogged, and likely drawn and quartered.  I found a blog from braintree, [here](https://www.braintreepayments.com/braintrust/safe-operations-for-high-volume-postgresql),  which suggests this is a safe operation but its a little vague.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `ALTER TABLE` command needs to acquire an `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock on the table, which will block everything trying to access that table, including `SELECT`s, and, as the name implies, needs to wait for existing operations to finish so it can be exclusive.

So, if your table is extremely busy, it may not get an opportunity to actually acquire the exclusive lock, and will simply block for what is functionally forever.

It also depends whether this column has a lot of indexes and dependencies. If there are dependencies (i.e. foreign keys or views), you'll need to add `CASCADE` to the `DROP COLUMN`, and this will increase the work that needs to be done, and the amount of time it will need to hold the exclusive lock.

So, it's not risk free. However, you should know fairly quickly after trying it whether it's likely to block for a long time. If you can try it and safely take a minute or two of potentially blocking that table, it's worth a shot -- try the drop and see. If it doesn't complete within a relatively short period of time, abort the command and you'll likely need to schedule some downtime of at least the app(s) that are hammering the table. (You can take a look at the server activity and the lock activity to try to surmise what's hammering that table.)

Comment: thanks for the insight and a quite thorough answer :)

Answer (score 3):

> *does drop column block a PostgreSQL database*

The answer to that is no, because it does not block the *database*.

However any DDL statement requires an *exclusive lock* on the table being changed. Which means no other transaction can access the *table*. So the table is "blocked", not the database.

However the time to drop a column is really very short, because the column isn't physically removed from the table but only marked as no longer there.

And don't forget to `commit` the DDL statement (if you have turned autocommit off), otherwise the table will be blocked until you commit your change.